# Why has my location history stopped working?

Tags: google-maps, google-location-history

From the time that Google Maps updated to the newest version, my device (Samsung Galaxy S3) no longer logs my location history althrought I have turned it on. I have tried uninstalling updates and installing them again, turning off and on location history but it still doesn't work.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is it just some kind of bug? Anyone?

Comment: Maybe connected to Latitude, which no longer is part of maps (and will be completely shut down in August)?

Comment: I have been connected to Latitude, but I don't think it has something to do with Maps & Location history, does it?

Comment: I never used Latitude, but AFAIK this was responsible for the location history as well. I'm not 100% sure, however; but it would explain things well, as the timing fits perfectly (the update broke it -- and the update removed Latitude).

Comment: So location history won't work anymore? Why don't I see anyone screaming about this? I bet I'm not the only one

Comment: I've seen them screaming in the forums. I myself never used that functionality (which is being moved to G+ btw), so I wouldn't even have noticed. I'm rather screaming for the crippled playstore (web) and now also the playstore app obviously having its "WiFi only" option removed and eating my data plan :(